# What are the most important points to emphasize while pitching for a dissertation to be published as a book?

Tags: phd, thesis, books, publishers

An editor for a major publishing house is visiting our institute, and some PhD students will get the chance to have a 15 min talk with them and discuss the publication of their dissertation as a book.

I would like to pitch my dissertation (a few months from completion) as a potential book for their publishing house. I am in the social sciences in Europe and there is no tradition of the authors getting any financial benefits out of their books, indeed sometimes we have to pay the publishers. But I would like to convince this one to 
a) Publish my diss
b) do it for free

What is the sort of **information that this editor would be the most interested to have** regarding my dissertation? **What important criteria do such editors consider** in coming to a decision regarding the publishability of Ph.D. dissertations?

Just to clarify, this is not a formal book proposal but only a short informal conversation, but one which I hope can be useful to both the editor and me.

Comment: (1) If possible, invite the editor to give a short presentation *answering this question* to all the PhD students (and faculty) in your department.  (2) Have you asked your advisor?  (3) Have you asked the editor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Editors need books that will have an audience, a point, impact, and a connection to their "lists".

In a conversation you should be able to briefly summarize your manuscript -- and in this summary make clear its central argument / narrative, scope / evidence base, and its what is novel, important, and exciting about it. You should also summarize the audience for the manuscript,  -- how it fits into the market: what other books are competing for this audience, and what distinguishes your manuscript. These summaries should be honest, and direct -- avoid both negativity and overstatement. Choose language to appeal to a smart, and critical, but not  specialize reader -- avoid jargon, and if you have to use specialized terms, define them briefly, in common-sense terms.

For a written prospectus, follow the same model, but expand to two pages; and include an outline of the work, list of figures/tables, and note any special features such as data, or an accompanying website.

For more details, see: Germano, *From Dissertation to Book* and Luey, *Handbook for Academic Authors*